# How to intercept back button in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, back-button, android-fragmentactivity

I'm new to android programming and I need help: I need to intercept back button in a Fragment to show an exit-alert-dialog. I tried both with onBackPressed and onKeyDown, but they don't work, I don't know why...
Here some code:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
    private Dialog dialog;
   // onAttach : set activity listener
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      // if implemented by activity, set listener
      // else create local listener (code never executed in this example)
   }

   // onCreateView : 
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      // fragment not when container null
      if (container == null) {
         return null;
      }
      // inflate view from layout
      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,container,false);

        ...

        //onBackPressed(); doesn't work, alertDialog comes up only the first time without touching back button
      return view;
   }
```

My "onBackPressed"...

```
public void onBackPressed() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Hey!")
                .setMessage("Exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    FragmentActivity i=getActivity(); 
                    i.finish();
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
        }

    }
```

Here for you also PagerTabsActivity and PagerAdapter, if you need...
PagerTabsActivity:

```
public class PagerTabsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static int i=0;
    private static View pagerStrip;
    // list contains fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    List<String> fragmentTitles = new Vector<String>();
    // page adapter between fragment list and view pager
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    // view pager
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // creating fragments and adding to list
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Home.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add(Home.class.getSimpleName());
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Second.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add(Second.class.getSimpleName());
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Third.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add(Third.class.getSimpleName());
        //
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerStrip = findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);
        if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTabStrip) {
            PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) pagerStrip;
            pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
            pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColorResource(android.R.color.white);
            // pagerTabStrip.setTextColor(color.white);
        } else if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTitleStrip) {
            PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) pagerStrip;
            pagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }

        this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    // private String titles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private List<String> fragmentTitles;
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        if (null == fragmentTitles || fragmentTitles.size() <= position) {
            return " ";
        }
        String fragTitle = fragmentTitles.get(position);
        if (null == fragTitle || fragTitle.trim().length() == 0) {
            return "No Title";
        }
        // Log.v("TitleAdapter - getPageTitle=", fragmentTitles.get(position));
        return fragmentTitles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // Log.v("TitleAdapter - getItem=", String.valueOf(position));
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: "show an exit-alert-dialog" -- that's a bad idea, simply because whatever data you are trying to save here can be lost in other ways (e.g., user presses HOME). Please do not interrupt the user with such dialogs. Instead, save any outstanding data to a temporary spot if you think it is not yet ready to apply to the main data store, and let the user know about that temporary data when they return to your app.

Comment: Thanks so much for this advice :) I'll keep it in mind! By the way, I'm doing only a very simple app with interactive mockups, so now I just want to know how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method.. try this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Exit")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .setPositiveButton("Get me out!", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                FragmentActivity i=getActivity(); 
                i.finish();
            }
        }).create().show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried, I've already posted a very similar code...I'll edit the first post to show it better!